An erotic comedy about Pentagon during Cold War
I saw this movie on a VHS videotape probably from late 80's.
It was in English, most probably filmed in the United States.
It was an erotic comedy.
I only remember two scenes from the movie.
There was a cleaning lady who, while cleaning the server room in the Pentagon, accidentally unplugged a military computer (looking like a thing from the 60's, with rolls of magnetic tape), which started blinking lights and spewing forth paper. The lady tried to fix the computer by pressing arbitrary buttons and putting the paper back, then ran away in panic.
The film ends with a scene of a paratrooper attack on a military base, the paratroopers turning out to the bare-breasted ladies, as the military personnel sees them through their binoculars.

The comedy Basic Training from 1985.

Melinda comes to Washington DC to visit her friend Debbie, and to find a job in government, where she hopes to do her part to make it better. She gets a lower echelon administrative position at the Pentagon, and finds things pretty slack. Her boss seems to be more interested in getting into her pants than trying to find lost data on the Russians. Melinda resists his advances and begins working her way up in the Pentagon, finding subtle ways of getting her policies implemented by manipulating the slovenly males that populate the Pentagon, including finding a way to defuse the mounting conflict with the Russians.

It contains both of the scenes you've mentioned. Here's the trailer (Warning: NSWF).


yeah, that's it, I recognize the actress now. Thanks!

Wow, that looks terrible! (In a wonderful way!)
